# Warning on field init order, signed comparison, and unused vars in VC++ & Sun Studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sunstudio

I am hoping to enable warnings for the following C++ compilation issues and corresponding compilers:

1. Unused variables -- **Sun Studio CC**

   Example: `void m() { int i = 10; }`
2. Signed to unsigned comparison - **VC++** and **Sun Studio CC**

   Example: `if ((unsigned) 10 < -1);`
3. Wrong field initialization order - **VC++** and **Sun Studio CC**

   Example: `class A { int i, j; A() : j(0), i(0) {} };`

All of these are caught by GCC and I would like to enable these in VC++ and Sun Studio.

```
bash-4.1$ g++ -Wall main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘void m()’:
main.cpp:1: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
main.cpp:1: warning: unused variable ‘i’
main.cpp: In constructor ‘A::A()’:
main.cpp:1: warning: ‘A::j’ will be initialized after
main.cpp:1: warning:   ‘int A::i’
main.cpp:1: warning:   when initialized here
```

---

**EDIT:** Outside enabling signed to unsigned comparison warnings on VC++, all other options do not seem to be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio, Project Properties, C++, set warning level to 4 (maximum) - VC++ compiler gives all possible warnings. AFAIK, warnings 1 and 2 are reported, and field initialization order is not reported by VC++ compiler.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is still the case with vc2015?  Some special flag somewhere?

Comment: Not yet. https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/2553854-c-compiler-should-warn-about-wrong-member-initia